# Books about the development/history of gravitational theory

Tags: physics, reference-request, relativity-theory, gravity

I am looking for a book about the history of gravitational theory. It should obviously include discussions of Newton, Einstein, and their theories, and hopefully it would include the work of other famous scientists (philosophers) like Aristotle and Galileo that were part of the development. It would be great to find a book that also discusses lesser known theories, like Le Sage's, Descartes's, or Nordstrom's and theories like MOND.

I have come across three books that might fit this but am looking for recommendations of which of these, or another related book, is best.

The Ascent of Gravity by Marcus Chown ("the force that explains everything".. ehh)

Gravity's Arc by David Darling

Gravity by George Gamow

Comment: Related [What 19th century developments contributed to the General theory of Relativity?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2395/55)

Answer (score 1):

The first two chapters of this book discuss the history of gravitational theory:

- Robert Grant, [History of physical astronomy from the earliest ages to
  the middle of the nineteenth century](https://archive.org/details/historyphysical00grangoog)